# Let $x,y,z,t$ be elements of a ring $R$ such that $xz=yt=1,xt=yz=0$ and $zx+ty=1$. Prove that the left $R$-modules $R$ and $R \oplus R$ are isomorphic

Tags: ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

this is a question that comes from UCLA algebra qualifying 2005 fall. I have been confused for two days but have no idea how to show this isomorphism.
Obviously, $R$ is not a commutative ring.

Comment: A linear map from R to R+R is given by a 2-by-1 matrix, and a linear map R+R to R is given by a 1-by-2 matrix: propose two such matrices , and write down the conditions that they are mutually inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez 's suggestion, I found it amazing to block R by matrix. Assuming we have matrix $A: R\oplus R \rightarrow R$ by $\left [ \begin{matrix}
c & d
\end{matrix} \right ] *\left [ \begin{matrix}
r_1 \\
r_2  \\
\end{matrix} \right ] $  where $(r_1,r_2) \in R$ and $B: R \rightarrow R\oplus R$ by $\left [ \begin{matrix}
a \\
b  \\
\end{matrix} \right ] *r $ where $r \in R.$ Then by composition of the two maps we must have $AB=Id_R$ and $BA=Id_{R\oplus R}$
Compare the coefficient in the matrix, we have A= $\left [ \begin{matrix}
z & t
\end{matrix} \right ]$ and $B=\left [ \begin{matrix}
x \\
y  \\
\end{matrix} \right ]$

Comment: It's not my idea, i don't recall who was the first one to carry this out. I guess you'll find references in Lam's book on rings.